# Why does moving the console.log() for a variable into a second AJAX call change the output?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsonp

I'm not quite sure why my code's output changes when I move the console.log() into the second AJAX call.

By splitting the three console.logs between the two AJAX calls, this code returns what I want (all productTitles with their productURLs and numProductTopics):

http://pastie.org/8067201

But after moving all three console.logs into the second AJAX call, this code returns the same productTitle and productURL every time with the differing, desired numProductTopics:

http://pastie.org/8067203

Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 1):

This is because you have a for loop where you assign value to your variables and start an ajax call, which will get executed before your ajax success callback executes. So they will hold the value of that last iteration.

```
for (var i=0;i < results.data.length; i++) {
var object = results.data[i];
if (object.canonical_name && object.name) {
    var productTitle = object.name;
        productURL = "getsatisfaction.com/trinet/products/" + object.canonical_name;
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: apiBaseURL + 'topics.json?product=' + object.canonical_name,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(results2) {
            var numProductTopics = results2.total;
            console.log(productTitle); //<-- this will have the value from last iteration
            console.log(productURL);//<-- this will have the value from last iteration
            console.log(numProductTopics);  
        }
    });
}
```

You can also resolve it by enclosing the variables for each loop int the ajax call by making it a function invocation. bacically you want to lockin the variables as closure variables for each iteration.

```
for (var i=0;i < results.data.length; i++) {
var object = results.data[i];
if (object.canonical_name && object.name) {
    var productTitle = object.name;
        productURL = "getsatisfaction.com/trinet/products/" + object.canonical_name;
   (function(productTitle, productURL){ //<-- Take the arguments
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: apiBaseURL + 'topics.json?product=' + object.canonical_name,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(results2) {
            var numProductTopics = results2.total;
            console.log(productTitle); 
            console.log(productURL);
            console.log(numProductTopics);  
        }
    });
   })(productTitle, productURL); //Lock in the variables here invoking the function call.
}
```

#### [FIddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6NhH/)

Comment: I see, thank you! How would you suggest I access all three of those variables with the desired values so I can insert them into an HTML unordered list?

Comment: You could just insert them in the success call back as you want. but since it is ajax call order cannot be guaranteed, so would need insert them accordingly if the order in the html matters, simple jquery would help you though.

Comment: @MichelleGlauser probably something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/PdaHL/ If i was able to answer your specific question please remember to mark as answer.